# Can not see wikitude poi in camera in android emulator

Tags: android, wikitude

I am learning about augmented reality. I am used wikitude sdk. I run sample exmaple in mobile device that working fine.

But i want to run sample example in emulator. Can't not show markers(POI point of interest).

I had attached camera with emulator. and latitude and longitude of current location.

Please help me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android**:

According to the [Wikitude SDK Documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/3.1/android/samples.html) you cannot run Wikitude SDK project on Android Emulator due to OpenGL restrictions.

**iOS**:

Please have a look at a [similar StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495658/hi-i-am-trying-to-execute-the-wikitude-sample-application-but-i-am-getting-thes).

Comment: If you have Wikitude android good document please share with me. I read from wikitude site. That document is very complicated.